# Need assistance to convert a json file to CSV

Tags: json, csv, parsing

I have a json file named "test.json" stated below and would like to convert it as a CSV file. I have tried with python pandas but unfortunately not succeeded.
Any assistance from someone will be really appreciative.

```js
{
 "epoch": 1487237243.000440,
 "comment": null,
 "header": "mac[#mode|_rate]       :    latitude     longitude   range     max     age    sig_A  noise_A    sig_B  noise_B    num loss      kBps",
 "data": {
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0000": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -96.00, -98.00, 2, 0, 0.138],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0001": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.50, -101.00, -96.50, -102.50, 2, 0, 0.438],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0002": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.50, -99.50, -96.00, -101.00, 2, 0, 1.538],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0003": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -97.00, -101.00, 1, 0, 0.138],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0004": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -96.00, -101.00, 1, 0, 0.438],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0005": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -95.00, -98.00, 1, 0, 1.538],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0006": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -95.00, -98.00, 1, 0, 0.138],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0007": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -96.50, -101.00, 2, 0, 0.438],
  "04:e5:48:01:73:29#0008": [48.1499800, 11.5833270, -1.00, 0.00, 0.00, -80.00, -101.00, -96.50, -99.50, 2, 0, 1.538]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If `filter.jq` contains the following filter

```
  [ .header | match("[^: ]+";"g") | .string ]
, ( .data   | keys[] as $k  | [$k] + .[$k] )
| @csv
```

and `data.json` contains the sample data then

```
$ jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
"mac[#mode|_rate]","latitude","longitude","range","max","age","sig_A","noise_A","sig_B","noise_B","num","loss","kBps"
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0000",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-96,-98,2,0,0.138
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0001",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80.5,-101,-96.5,-102.5,2,0,0.438
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0002",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80.5,-99.5,-96,-101,2,0,1.538
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0003",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-97,-101,1,0,0.138
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0004",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-96,-101,1,0,0.438
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0005",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-95,-98,1,0,1.538
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0006",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-95,-98,1,0,0.138
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0007",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-96.5,-101,2,0,0.438
"04:e5:48:01:73:29#0008",48.14998,11.583327,-1,0,0,-80,-101,-96.5,-99.5,2,0,1.538
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution using `jsonlite` and `dplyr`:

```
install.packages(c("jsonlite","dplyr"))
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

# asumme your file is "my_file.json"
my_data <- as_tibble(fromJSON("my_file.json"))
```